# call to asmx from c# windows service, once fails, never recovers

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a c# windows service that calls an asmx web service every 5 minutes. This program runs on windows server 2003 with .net 4.0

The program calls the asmx file just fine until something happens like the server with the asmx on it is not available and then it gets a timeout. That makes perfects sense but after the server with the asmx is back up, the c# client continues to get timeouts. I have to restart the c# client to correct the problem.

Here is the client code(nothing fancy here):

```
using (var service = new WebService())
{
    try
    {
        pairs = service.EventProcessor(packet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error("Choked on sending the event\r\n{0}\r\n{1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace);
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            Logger.Error("Inner Exception\r\n{0}\r\n{1}", e.InnerException.Message, e.InnerException.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to debug to see whats going on?

Comment: The code is on a customer site. I don't know how to debug that. I added the innerException check which may give me more information. However, each call creates a new WebService object. I wonder if there is something cached somewhere in that object???

Comment: yes, it will create a new WebService object and that is fine, it is also being disposed of since you have a using block there. I suggest taking the code project and putting it on your system and debug it. otherwise if its possible, attach the remote debugger.